# It is possible to login a consumer in Azure B2C using a JWT token?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've seen in some CIAM platforms that is possible to authenticate the consumers and create a session using JWT token, like for example in Firebase: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/create-custom-tokens

Is this option possible and available with Azure B2C?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such equivalent thing in Azure B2C, you could not login a consumer via a JWT token.

Comment: hi @joy, thank you for answering. However, I don't think is correct based on this example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-nodejs-webapi --> It seems IT IS possible

Comment: @VictorNavarro In this sample, it uses auth code flow to get the token for the user, then use the token to call the web api, but it does not equal login the user with the token, because the token will be obtained after the user interactive login i.e. with username and password.

Comment: yes, that's right. I guess, then there's no way to auto-login the consumer :(

Comment: i just want to be sure that the answer is correct before accepting it. I will do in a few days if I can't find a way. Thanks